# How to invoke a method of a class from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a **project A**, an mvc5 project with entityframework 6 and Oracle ManagedDataAccess. This project has a `NewsletterX` class and this class has an asynchronous `SendNewsletter` method, without parameters, which is used in a controller of this project.
I also have a **project B**, a Windows Service project, where I intend to use the `SendNewsletter` method (`NewsletterX` class). What philosophy should I use? Reference project A? Create a DLL for `NewsletterX` class and reference it in **project B**? 
In **project B**, will I have to reference EntityFramework and Oracle ManagedDataAccess?

Comment: That depends. Does `NewsletterX` class or `SendNewsletter` use EntityFramework or Oracle ManagedDataAccess?

Comment: A is a mvc project, `SendNewsletter` uses the data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. In **project B**, in addition to referencing **project A**, I also referenced the Entityframework and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

Comment: Which probably had the side effect of modifying the config file in the same way that the error message told you to. It doesn't mean that project B necessarily needed those references, just that adding them fixed other things up so an observed problem went away

Answer (score 0):

There's little practical difference between B referencing project A and B referencing a DLL built by project A, other than the ability to step between the two projects when debugging/see the code of both projects in front of you

You don't need B to reference all the DLLs A makes use of, just for B to be able to use A; A already references then. They will, however, need to be deployed to the target machine somewhere that the loader can find them when B runs and invokes methods in A.

Comment: A is a project with a large dimension, B is a very small project. Does it make sense to refer all project A? Is this really what people do?

Comment: I referenced project A in project B, invoked method `SendNewsletter` . The result was this:
"No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file"

Comment: "It depends" is the answer to the first question. I use a DLL in some web projects that is 18 megabytes when compiled.

Comment: The second seems logical; DLLs don't contain config information, and it'll be looking to find its config info from the file that is storing settings for the app the DLL is loaded into add the config settings to the file as per the error message